# Filter pane bug in modern experience when using a calcuated column

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, filter, 2019

I've run into an odd bug when using the filter pane to filter a calculated column in SharePoint 2019 on premise.

When using the *see all* option, the "8_" text is added to the filter value and the filter is not working as expected.

This happens on all major browsers!

Any idea how to fix this?

Please see attached animated gif!

Many thanks,
Adrian

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue.

As a workaround, try to use the "Filter by" in the column drop down menu to filter this calculated column.

Besides, you can submit this issue in the [User Voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) for your convenience, it is a place for customers provide feedback about Microsoft SharePoint products .

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I thought about using the workaround you mentioned but then the column would appear in the filter pane and the users would still be tempted to use the see all option.